# How to fix 'Variable not defined' in custom modules

Tags: python, function, class, input, python-module

I'm currently still learning python but am doing well so far so I decided to take on a larger project where I build a short text based game and use custom modules to separate my code. Unfortunately I have run into numerous complications and fixed those problems with some google and patience applied vigorously but this one is stumping me.

The problem itself is that I have two files that I am working with: main.py and roomsClass.py. In main.py there is the request for input and the command to turn input to lower but then I try to transfer that input to the functions in gameRooms.py and it just won't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated and if I did anything wrong in this post please let me know. I am brand new to stackoverflow and can take any pointers I can get.

I tried to globally assign it in the individual module but I have to define the input variable again and this causes my code to pop up a useless input point.

Also tried to import main to the file but that creates too many dependencies between gameRooms and main.

main.py

```
userInput = input('\nWhat shall you do? :> ')
gameInput = userInput.lower()
```

gameRooms.py

```
class Rooms():

    def __init__(self, pos, name, desc, exits, status, nLock, sLock, eLock, wLock):
        self.pos = pos
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.exits = exits
        self.status = status
        self.nLock = nLock
        self.sLock = sLock
        self.eLock = eLock
        self.wLock = wLock

    def lookRoom(self):
        global userInput
        global gameInput

        if gameInput in cfg.lookList and self.pos == cfg.xyMap:
            print(f"\n{self.name}")
            print(f"\n\t{self.desc}")
```

That is just a little bit of the module but just what I am trying to fix. Mainly just the gameInput in lookRoom(self):.

I expect it to actually let me use the user input from main.py but the output just says gameInput is not defined.

Comment: Where and how do you call the `lookRoom()` method?

Comment: "I try to transfer that input to the functions in gameRooms.py" Please show the code that is supposed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should do some changes in your code, this changes will make your code sounds more *Pythonic*.

Changes in `main.py`, put your code in a function with return:

```
def game_input():
    userInput = input('\nWhat shall you do? :> ')
    gameInput = userInput.lower()

    return gameInput
```

Changes in `gameRooms.py`:

- You should add a new variable `gameInput` in your constructor class.
- Do some alterations in your function `lookRoom()`.
- import your module `main.py`.

```
import main

class Rooms():

    def __init__(self, pos, name, desc, exits, status, nLock, sLock, eLock, wLock, gameInput):
        self.pos = pos
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.exits = exits
        self.status = status
        self.nLock = nLock
        self.sLock = sLock
        self.eLock = eLock
        self.wLock = wLock

        self.gameInput = gameInput

    def lookRoom(self):

        if self.gameInput in cfg.lookList and self.pos == cfg.xyMap:
            print(f"\n{self.name}")
            print(f"\n\t{self.desc}")
```

Now when you create a new object `Rooms()` you have to informe all params, even the param `gameInput`

Take a look:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    gameInput = main.game_input()

    r1 = Rooms("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", gameInput)
    #r1.lookRoom()
```

You can even use a `while` statement for force the user inform the `gameInput`, here's a example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        gameInput = main.game_input()

        if gameInput == "":
            print("Type your name correctly!")
        else:
            break

    r1 = Rooms("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", gameInput)    
    #r1.lookRoom()
```

---

**EDIT 1**:

`gameRooms.py`:

```
class Rooms():

    def __init__(self, pos, name, desc, exits, status, nLock, sLock, eLock, wLock, gameInput):
        self.pos = pos
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.exits = exits
        self.status = status
        self.nLock = nLock
        self.sLock = sLock
        self.eLock = eLock
        self.wLock = wLock

        self.gameInput = gameInput

    def lookRoom(self):
        if self.gameInput in cfg.lookList and self.pos == cfg.xyMap:
            print(f"\n{self.name}")
            print(f"\n\t{self.desc}")
```

`main.py`:

```
from gameRooms import *

def game_input():
    userInput = input('\nWhat shall you do? :> ')
    gameInput = userInput.lower()

    return gameInput


if __name__ == '__main__':

    gameInput = game_input()

    r1 = Rooms("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", gameInput)
    #r1.lookRoom()
```

Comment: Thank you so much you cleared up a lot of things for me. Another question though is how do I deal with the interdependency between main.py and gameRooms.py as they each import the other and that causes issues?

Comment: In this example, only the `gameRooms.py` imports `main.py`, but you can use `main.py` as main class and import `gameRooms.py` to it. You also can create another class and import everything to it and run everything in it. In my opnion you should use the `main.py` as main class and import everything to it, if you do it you can't need import `main.py` to `gameRooms.py`. I'll edit the post and show you a example to you.